# Rails 5 api only app with home page

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-5

I have generated a rails 5 api application. But I want my app with home page. For that I generated a home controller and added view file i respective views/home/index.html.erb

But when I tried accessing it I am getting below response

> Started GET "/home/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-14 11:14:03 +0530
>   Processing by HomeController#index as HTML Completed 204 No Content in
>   0ms
>
> Started GET "/home/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-14 11:14:20
>   +0530 Processing by HomeController#index as JS Completed 204 No Content in 0ms

But I could not see index page content displayed on the web.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was in the same boat, trying to do a Rails 5 API app that could still bootstrap from a single html page (taken over by JS on load). Stealing a hint from [rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/welcome_controller.rb), I created the following controller (note that it's using Rails' instead of my `ApplicationController` for this lone non-api controller)

```
require 'rails/application_controller'

class StaticController < Rails::ApplicationController
  def index
    render file: Rails.root.join('public', 'index.html')
  end
end
```

and put the corresponding static file (plain `.html`, not `.html.erb`) in the `public` folder. I also added

```
get '*other', to: 'static#index'
```

at the end of `routes.rb` (after all my api routes) to enable preservation of client-side routing for reloads, deep links, etc.

Without setting root in `routes.rb`, Rails will serve directly from public on calls to `/` and will hit the static controller on non-api routes otherwise. Depending on your use-case, adding `public/index.html` (without root in `routes.rb`) might be enough, or you can achieve a similar thing without the odd `StaticController` by using

```
get '*other', to: redirect('/')
```

instead, if you don't care about path preservation.

I'd love to know if anyone else has better suggestions though.

Comment: Nice! I had the same problem and you helped me. But you don´t need "layout false" line.

Comment: This is the right answer and allows client-side routing solution (i.e. React Router) to pick up the route and render the right thing. What I do to have my controllers all "look" the same is create an ApiController and an ApplicationController inheriting from ActionController::API and ActionController::Base, respectively. Then inherit from ApplicationController for StaticController and all others can inherit from ApiController.

Comment: This didn't work in my Rails 7 app since I didn't have the file renderer. My workaround was to pretend I was serving XML and override the content type: `render xml: File.read(Rails.root.join('public', 'index.html')), content_type: 'text/html'`

Answer (score 0):

**Just to add to [Risto Keravuori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406528/10907864)**

I had to create a **home controller** in the `app/controllers` directory:

```
app/controllers/home_controller.rb
```

Next, I added the following content to it:

```
require 'rails/application_controller'

class HomeController < Rails::ApplicationController
  def index
    render file: Rails.root.join('public', 'index.html')
  end
end
```

Then, I created an **index.html** file in the `public` directory:

```
public/index.html
```

Next, I added the following content to it:

```
<head>
  <title>My API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My API</h1>
    <p>Welcome to my API</p>
</body>
```

**Note**: You can modify the index.html file based on your choice.

Lastly, I added the routes to the `config/routes.rb` file, below all the already defined routes.

```
get '*other', to: 'home#index'
```

**Note**: Do not put it inside a namespace say, `api` namespace or `api/v1` namespace. Just put it at the bottom of the file but inside the `Rails.application.routes.draw do` block.

You can restart your server and test it out.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is just a static HTML page (with some simple css/js), i think another method is just to edit the `index.html` page under `public` folder.

Comment: this is correct just create an index.html file inside the public folder not need to make a new routes/controller

Comment: This is Rail API controller, it is not serve static public pages