# I want to use view on Rails5 api mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Tried

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

 root to: 'welcome#index'
 resource :lookouts do
   collection do
     get :cover
   end
 end
end
```

`welcome_controller.rb`

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :html
  end
end
```

`welcome/index.html.erb`

```
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">

 <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

 <h1>hello</h1>
```

How can I use erb template on rails 5 api mode
I heard that we can't use erb on rails5 api mode but I want to use.

Comment: I think better use json views, I perfer jbuilder for it https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: No I wanna make a view to introduce this API.

Comment: So you want some controllers to be API controllers and some to be regular controllers?

Comment: Yeah, yes I want do so

Comment: So you don't need to create rails API app. I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366501/rails-5-api-only-app-with-home-page) you can find solution

Comment: Thanks that's my solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 5 api only app with home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366501/rails-5-api-only-app-with-home-page)